# i want to use two tableview in single viewcontroller. but what sgould be a final return type?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

i want to use two tableview in single viewcontroller. but what sgould be a final return type?

here is my code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(tableView == self.tableaudiodata){
        let cell:customcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell") as! customcell
        cell.audiolabel.text = recordings[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent
        return cell
    }
    if(tableView == self.tablehome){
        let cell:homecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("homecell") as! homecell
        let dic = arrayofhomedata.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        cell.homelbl.text = dic["key"] as! NSString as String
        print(arrayofhomedata.valueForKey("value"))
        return cell
    }
          What should be return here???}
```

Comment: You can return nil here. Or change your second if statement into an else.

Comment: return UITableViewCell()

Comment: nil is not allowed, you need to return an UITableViewCell -ill prefer to use just an else statement.

Comment: Sorry, forgot I was looking at Swift, you should use an else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use the "tag" Attribute to specify which tableView gets called from the delegate. Set your "tag" attribute in Xcode or in code by using:

```
tableview.tag = 1
tableviewDetail.tag = 2
```

When you "reload" the data, the delegate asks for the methods to return the cells for the selected tableView.

For example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 if tableView.tag = 1 {
    //return your main Cell 
 } else {
    //return the other cell (dont use "2" here, because the delegate always needs to return a cell)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if(tableView == self.tableaudiodata){
          let cell:customcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell") as! customcell
          cell.audiolabel.text = recordings[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent
         return cell
        }
        else if(tableView == self.tablehome){
          let cell:homecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("homecell") as! homecell
          let dic = arrayofhomedata.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
          cell.homelbl.text = dic["key"] as! NSString as String
          print(arrayofhomedata.valueForKey("value"))
         return cell
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using different datasources (and maybe delegates?) for each tableview, that will make things a lot simpler in the long run.

```
tableview1.datasource = MyNewDataSource()
tableview2.datasource = MyOtherDataSource()
```